# Cannot submit a transcation in composer playground?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

**Problem:**

I have created and deployed a business network in `https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net`. There I can create participant and assets as I expected. But Submit Transaction button is disable.

This is my .cto file.Where I wrote business network model.

```
    namespace org.landreg

    abstract concept Address {
      o String addressLine
      o String locality
    }

    concept DutchAddress {
      o String postalCode regex=/\d{4}[ ]??[A-Z]{2}/
    }

    enum Gender {
      o FEMALE
      o MALE
    }

    participant Individual identified by passportNumber{
      o String passportNumber
      o DutchAddress address
      o Gender gender
    }

    asset  LandTitle identified by id {
      o String id
      o DutchAddress address
      o Integer area range=[1000,]
      o Boolean forSale default=false
      o Double price optional
      --> Individual owner
      --> Individual[] previousOwners
    }

    abstract transaction UnlockLandTitle {
      -->LandTitle landTitle
    }
```

This is my logic.js file.Where I define the transaction.

```
    /*
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    "use strict";
    /**
     * Write your transction processor functions here
     */

    const NS = "org.landreg";

    /**
     * Sample transaction
     * @param {org.landreg.UnlockLandTitle} tx //transaction object define in the cto file
     * @transaction
     */
    async function UnlockLandTitle(tx) {
      //Get asset registery for landTitles
      const landTitleRegistry = await getAssetRegistry(NS + ".LandTitle");

      if (tx.landTitle.forSale) {
        throw new Error(
          `Land Title with id ${tx.landTitle.getIdentifier()} is already unlocked for sale`
        );
      }

      // Unlock asset to be for sale
      tx.landTitle.forSale = true;

      await landTitleRegistry.update(tx.landTitle);
    }
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Because without solving this I cannot go forward.I search and try to solve this problem.But I was unable to find any solution for this problem.Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your **`Model(.cto)`** file.

You can not use **abstract** with **transaction**, just remove abstract keyword.

```
transaction UnlockLandTitle {
   --> LandTitle landTitle
}
```